# Float delimeter changes inside required file

Tags: php, locale

There is a class, that collects some data and renders the result.

It's main method CollectExpress() sets locale for numerics, collects data and then uses other class method to draw a template with collected data.

```
public function CollectExpress() {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');

    //collecting data 
    //...

    echo $this->DrawExpress($collection);

}

public function DrawExpress($collection) {
    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush(false);
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content/express.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Collection data is an associative array. The problem is that collection's float elements inside the template express.php change their delimiter from "." to ",".

I've added dump of collection data to the express.php

```
<?php
var_dump($collection);
?>
<div class="collection">
     <!--template output-->
</div>
<?php
var_dump($collection);
?>
```

Data before start of output has "." as float delimeter, but when output starts it switches to ",". What's the reason of changing locale inside the template and how to fix it?